# Check empty output from fish function

Tags: fish

I have the following function that prints my current IP:

```
function get_ip
  echo -n -s (ifconfig en1 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}')
end

$ get_ip
192.168.1.4~
```

I'm looking forward to print `offline` if `get_ip` returns nothing (it prints "" when I'm offline).

I tried:

```
if get_ip
  echo "Yes"
else
  echo "No"
end
```

But it always returns `Yes`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the exit status of the test builtin.

```
if test -n (get_ip) 
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
end
```

---

While testing, I found some inconsistency between `-n` and `-z` that I will follow up on. Try this:

```
if test -z (get_ip) 
    echo No
else
    echo Yes
end
```

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23233524/7552) from the fish maintainer, both answers are wrong, even though the 2nd one works. Use either

```
count (get_ip); and echo Y; or echo N
```

or

```
set result (get_ip)
test -n "$result"; and echo Y; or echo N
```

Comment: It's still returning always `Yes`.